# awk causing memory leak?

Tags: awk, memory-leaks

I am using awk to process a huge data file (about 100 million lines).

This is my expression-

```
tac <myfile> | awk -F',' 'OFS=\",\" {if(/^#/){print;}else{\$1=tolower(\$1);if(!seen[\$1]++)print;}}'|")
```

However, I'm seeing memory leak with awk.
Can someone point out the memory hog here?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's due to the 100 million lines? As long as it doesn't crash you should wait for it to finish, it could take hours.

Comment: And why are you escaping `"` and `$`? Is this line passed as a command to something else?

Comment: Also, more concise form, if you're using GNU awk: `awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '$1 && !(tolower($1) in seen) {seen[tolower($1)]=1; print}; !$1'` (See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html).

Comment: @muru I failed to see where seen in initialize ..

Comment: @pragmatic awk will build a hash with all different value of $1, if you have million of them, you should expect memory use by awk to grow. Now, IF you run awk, IF it ends OK, AND you see less memory after, that could be called a memory leak. have you seen one ?

Comment: @Archemar Initialize? To what?

Comment: First of all. awk is not suited for 100million lines. If you ask a real question and show what you would like to do with the processed lines, there might be another "faster" solution

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak?

Comment: @Archemar: Thanks for the detail. From top logs, I'm seeing awk gradually going for upto 99% memory usage. After that it comes down to ~92% and stays there. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @val0x00ff Can you suggest me any of the "faster" solution. As evident from my code snippet above, I'm just trying to read lines from one file. And writing it to another file as comma seperated values, making sure first entry is always in lower-case .

Comment: @muru Is your suggested command in anyway more efficient than mine? Sorry but I fail to see any difference. Also, escaping " and $ is part of my requirement.

Comment: Please add some number to your question: 1) file size (several GB I presume!); 2) Does your example finish? (How long does it take?); 3) What are the time restrictions?

Comment: @pragmatic The expensive part of your code is removing duplicates. You have to remember all the previous lines to do that, it's an intrinsic requirement of the problem. There are approaches that will use less memory than awk, but they will use a lot of memory anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that with the number of lines you present, you are probably swapping ...

The perl script below is using a B-tree in disk (something very common in databases) 
for the array -- we are using almost no RAM memory.

```
$ cat remdup
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DB_File;
tie %seen, 'DB_File', "mydbfile.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC ,0666, $DB_BTREE;

while(<>){
  if(/^#/)        { print; }
  elsif(/(.*?),/) { $a=lc($1);
                    print if( ! $seen{$a}++)}
}
```

anyway, it will take a long time to process (16s for 1 million lines in my 5 year old laptop)

Usage: `tac file | perl remdup > output`

Edit: if you run any of the solution please tell us the times.